# My code is throwing an error, I need to find out the reason

Tags: javascript, class

I am getting expected error in my code and I have no idea why.

',' expected. The ide is pointing at the closing curly bracket of function remove, the curly bracket before the last curly bracket

The console says, uncaught syntax error: missing ) after argument list

Write a method remove that removes the specified item from the storage and returns the removed item and if not found
return a string Not Found, incase there are multiple items with the same name return the first one found.

```js
class Safe {
  constructor(safeSize) {
    this.storage = [];
    this.safeSize = safeSize;
  }
  insert(name, size) {

    if (this.safeSize - size >= 0) {
      this.safeSize -= size;
      this.storage.push({
        name: size
      }); // push it as an object
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  remove(test) {
    let shouldSkip = false;
    this.storage.forEach(function(element, index) {

        if (shouldSkip) {
          return;
        }

        if (element === test) {
          shouldSkip = true;
          const removedItem = element;
          this.storage.pop(element);
          return ("The item" + removedItem + " Has been removed");
        }
        return (test + "  Item not found");
      }
    }
  }
```

```
> test cases:
>
> safe.insert("watermelon", 7);  => true 
> safe.insert("plate", 2);       => true
>
> safe.remove("money");           => "Not Found" 
> safe.remove("watermelon");      => {name: "watermelon", "size: 7"} 
> safe.remove("watermelon");      => "Not Found"
```

Comment: You say you're getting an expected error. Do you mean unexpected error? What is the error? Which line of code?

Comment: ',' expected.   that is all what I am getting
The ide is pointing at the closing curly bracket  of function remove
The curly bracket before the last curly bracket

Comment: The console says,  uncaught syntax error: missing ) after argument list

Comment: You have not terminated the `this.storage.forEach(...)` call correctly. It needs a matching parenthesis at line 33.

Comment: You need to have `});` after `return (test...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some wrong codes in your code.
Please use this code.

```
class Safe {
  constructor(safeSize) {
    this.storage = [];
    this.safeSize = safeSize;
  }
  insert(name, size) {

    if (this.safeSize - size >= 0) {
      this.safeSize -= size;
      this.storage.push({
        name, size
      }); // push it as an object
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  remove(test) {
    let shouldSkip = false;
    let message = "";
    this.storage = this.storage.filter( element => {
        if(element.name == test && !shouldSkip) {
            shouldSkip = true;
            message = "The item " + element.name + " Has been removed"
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
    if(!shouldSkip) message = test + " Item not found";
    return message;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was wondering why I was getting undefined while executing the remove function.
I used shouldSkip because I wanted to terminate the forEach loop when it finds an item, which should solve the duplicate issue if found

I will test your code, thank you again !

Comment: In this code, I don't use "this.storage.pop(element);".
And I used "shouldSkip" for confirmed that an element is removed.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer, I am just wondering why my code can't enter the array from the first place because when I execute it no errors, but when I try the test cases:<br/>

``safe.insert("watermelon", 7); // => true         getting true here<br/>
safe.insert("plate", 2); // => true                     getting true here<br/>

safe.remove("money"); // => "Not Found"         getting undefined here<br/>
safe.remove("watermelon"); // => {name: "watermelon", "size: 7"}     getting <br/>undefined here
safe.remove("watermelon"); // => "Not Found"               getting undefined here``

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the closing parenthesis for your forEach function:

```
  remove(test) {
    let shouldSkip = false;
    this.storage.forEach(function(element, index) {

        if (shouldSkip) {
          return;
        }

        if (element === test) {
          shouldSkip = true;
          const removedItem = element;
          this.storage.pop(element);
          return ("The item" + removedItem + " Has been removed");
        }
        return (test + "  Item not found");
    }) //<------
  }
```